# How to make different row heights in every other column using a CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to get something like this using grid in CSS:

[image: desired layout]

How can I reach it?

I made this so far and I have no idea what further..

```css
#gallery {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

#gallery img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#gallery img:first-child {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1/3
}

#gallery img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 7;
  grid-row: 1/3
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="../images/.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution here using 2 fixed rows and auto-generating columns.

Problem: you loose an image every 6, as columns always contain 2 images, but one in 3 only shows one. You could insert a filler every 6 in html to compensate.

I used variables to avoid repeating the same values (image height and width) in several places.

I also made the margin-top for offsets in columns 0 and 1 a calculation for symmetry.

```css
:root {
  --img-width: 90px;
  --img-height: 120px;
  --img-offset: 50px;
}

#gallery {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, var(--img-height));
  grid-auto-columns: var(--img-width);
  height: var(--img-height);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray; border-left: none;
}

#gallery img {
  border-top: none;
  width: var(--img-width);
  height: var(--img-height);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,175,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,106,190,1) 100%);
  border: 1px solid gray; border-left: none;
}

#gallery .lost-pic {
  background: red; /* you will not see those */
}

/* column 0 */
#gallery img:nth-child(6n + 1),
#gallery img:nth-child(6n + 2) {
  margin-top: calc(0px - var(--img-height) + var(--img-offset));
}

/* column 1 */
#gallery img:nth-child(6n + 3),
#gallery img:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  margin-top: calc(0px - var(--img-offset));
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <!--column 0-->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <!--column 1-->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <!--column 2-->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="" class="lost-pic"> <!-- This will be invisible -->
  <!--column 0-->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <!--column 1-->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <!--column 2-->
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="" class="lost-pic"> <!-- This will be invisible -->
</div>
```